# creating a function with varying array sizes as parameters

Tags: arrays, c++11, resize

So I am really unsure about how to even ask this question, so it was hard for me to look this up. I made the title the best that I could to fit the question. So, lets get into it.
I am making a project to run the game fore&aft, and I need to be able to pass an array into a function. So right now I have something similar to this:

```
//global
const int sizeFive = 5;

//functions    
void function(string m[][sizeFive]){}

int main(){
string GAME_BOARD[sizeFive][sizeFive];
//populate GAME_BOARD here
function(GAME_BOARD);
}
```

Now this works for the game board on a 5x5 board. However, one of the requirements for the project is that it also needs to work on a 7x7, 9x9, and 11x11 board size.
I also have the following global variables.

```
int SIZE; //size that is not const and assigned in main from user input
const int sizeSeven = 7; //size I want to use for 7x7 board
const int sizeNine = 9; //size I want to use for 9x9 board
const int sizeEleven = 11; //size I want to use for 11x11 board
```

So is it possible to make my function calls change, maybe by using SIZE, after the user inputs the size of the board they want? If so, how is this possible? Right now the best idea I had was to make 4 different files, 1 for each size, and let it call those after the user inputs the size in the driver file. However, this seems ineffecient and seems like it will take up more space than really needed (not optimal). 
Thanks in advance for any help you are able to give!

Comment: Templates? Or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: I haven't really worked with templates, so I will look into those. I have used vectors a lot, but the way this is working seems weird to use a vector. But maybe I will look into that again too.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> GAME_BOARD(sizeFive, std::vector<std::string>(sizeFive));`. For example.

Comment: How would that be different in the function calls for the varying sizes?

Comment: Just pass e.g. `GAME_BOARD` and check its size?

Comment: so i could just have <vector<vector<string>> as the parameter, and it wont care about size?

Comment: That's correct. The size isn't part of the type for vectors.

Comment: awesome. I almost have it working for vectors. I think my only issue right now is that I have a struct and in it i make a vector<vector<string>>m(SIZE, vector<string>(SIZE)); However, it says that the first SIZE is not a type name, which is weird because it works everywhere else.

Comment: vector<vector<string>> m = (vector<string>(SIZE), vector<vector<string>>(SIZE));
Does this line work the same as the vector<vector<string>>m(SIZE, vector<string>>(SIZE);

Comment: what is SIZE? and what you mean by that expression. you have to read on how to use vectors. check  reserve() method.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have is flawed and will lead nowhere. The simple reason is that the sizes of an array are part of its type, which are also part of the function signature. This is set at compile time and constant from there on. No user-supplied input can ever change this.

Now, how can you fix this? The first thing to do is to create an object that holds the field. This object provides access to the fields (like the array) and also provides the size (to get rid of the nasty global). The difference is that it can be initialized to different sizes.

Your `function()` doesn't loop from `0` to `sizeFive` then but from `0` to `field.size()`, just to give an example. Instead of accessing the raw array as `field[x][y]` it requests the fields like `field.get(x, y)`.